# changing the values specified on the axis - matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, octave

I am trying to generate the following graph:

[image: Picture is attached.]

Up until now I managed to do the following:

> >
>   close all
>   figure(1)
>   x=-12:0.3:12;
>   y=gaussmf(x,[3 3]);
>   xlim([-12,12])
>   plot(x,y,'go-','LineWidth',2)
>   y1=gaussmf(x,[3 -3]);
>   xlim([-15,15])
>   hold on
>   plot(x,y1,'b-s','LineWidth',2)
>   hold on
>   line([-3,-3],[1,0],'color','black','LineWidth',2);
>   hold on
>   line([3,3],[1,0],'color','black','LineWidth',2);

I didn't manage to adjust the x axis so it will mark the values -12:3:12 instead of -15:5:15.

Comment: Is maybe the problem concerning the xlim? xlim([-15,15]) -> xlim([-12,12]). I can't get your question.

Comment: There's one problem, ---> your problem is not clear enough :( can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I guess someone did understand my proble. next time I will be more carefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wanting your tick locations in different places? You can set them manually by changing the 'Xtick' property of your graphics object, as in

```
set(gca,'xtick', -12:3:12)
```